# How to get asserts in mocha before blocks to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, crash, mocha.js

How to get asserts in mocha before blocks to work? If I am not suppose to do this let me know. Currently, using promises, if I get an error using an catch block, I'll add an assert to fail the before block. WHat I want is it to fail the describe block, but instead I get two possible outcomes. 1. My test suite completely crashes, 2. I have to wait for each timeout to hit for each test because the before block failed.

```
before(function (done) {
    promise()
        .then(function () {
            done();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            assert(!error);
            done();
        });
});
```

I even tried this, thinking, maybe the done was never called.

```
before(function (done) {
    promise()
        .then(function () {
            //no done here
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            assert(!error);
        });
        .finally(function () {
            done();
        });
});
```

So far to avoid crashing and waiting, and to make it work, I have done this:

```
var beforeError;
before(function (done) {
    promise()
        .then(function () {
            done();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            beforeError = error;
            done();
        });
});

it('test something', function () {
    assert(beforeError, 'Before block failed with error.');
});
```

I am really curious if there is a better way to go about this so that if my before/beforeEach/after/afterEach blocks fail, it doesn't cause me to wait ages or my suite to crash! Thanks S/O community! :)

Comment: Just call done with the error. `done(err)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to your use of the `done` callback, but mocha 3.0 supports [promises in before hooks](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) now. Were I to write this, I would let the returned promise throw its own error, which will fail the before hook without breaking the suite.

```
before(function () {
    return promise(<async behavior here>);
});
```